# Should I import internal modules to declare my function types?

Tags: haskell, module

When declaring types for my functions I noticed that I need to import additional constructors from 'Internal' modules just for that purpose. Here is one (simplified) example:

```
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Data.Text.Internal
import Data.ByteString.Internal

foo :: Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString -> Data.Text.Internal.Text   
foo = decodeUtf8
```

Those modules are named 'Internal' for some purpose I presume. Yet they carry types that are exported to public. Is it good practice to explicitly depend on them?

Comment: You could just import Data.ByteString and Data.Text, or does this not work for some reason?

Comment: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Data.Text.Internal.Text'. I figured that I need to import and declare the types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Text` type is *declared* in `Data.Text.Internal`. However, it is re-exported from `Data.Text`, so just importing that module should give you everything you need.

I think the problem is that you're referring to the type as `Data.Text.Internal.Text`; if you refer to it simply as `Text` it should work:

```
import Data.ByteString
import Data.Text

foo :: ByteString -> Text
```